# Facebook PHP SDK - Throws exception when trying to fetch profile data

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Below is the part of exception object that I get when trying to fetch logged in users profile data

PHP Code

```
$user = $facebook->api('/me');
```

Exception that I get

```
object(FacebookApiException)#3 (7) {
  ["result:protected"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["error_code"]=>
    int(77)
    ["error"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["message"]=>
      string(104) "error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
"
      ["type"]=>
      string(13) "CurlException"
    }
  }
  ["message:protected"]=>
  string(104) "error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
"
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The error message is very explicit. I don't do FB dev but it's quite clear that your files are not located where it expects them to be. And obviously you can try{ ... }catch(Exception $Exception){ ... } the Exception.

Comment: What are you using Curl for? To get the accesstoken?

Comment: the cURL is being used in PHP SDK file that I downloaded from facebook github repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks like a problem with CURL is unable to write to your ssl folder, one workaround may be try to force curl to not establish secure connection. something like this you can do:

```
curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

OR

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

Comment: However, that will mean you no longer are sure that `https://facebook.com` really is what it claims to be. The "fix" should be in getting this feature to work, not disabling it.

Answer (score 2):

Recheck that you have the certificate in the the src folder

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt